# MVC setting up Html.DropdownList on ModelState.IsValid = false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, modelstate, dropdownlistfor

This is something that has always puzzled me as to the best way round, while keeping maintainable code. The below code sets up a list of months and years for a payment gateway form, before assigning these to a variable of type `List<SelectListItem>`.

**Intial Action**

```
PayNowViewModel paymentGateway = new PayNowViewModel();
List<SelectListItem> paymentGatewayMonthsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
List<SelectListItem> paymentGatewayYearsList = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
    selectListItem.Value = i.ToString();
    selectListItem.Text = i.ToString("00");

    paymentGatewayMonthsList.Add(selectListItem);
}

int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
for (int i = year; i <= year + 10; i++)
{
    SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
    selectListItem.Value = i.ToString();
    selectListItem.Text = i.ToString("00");

    paymentGatewayYearsList.Add(selectListItem);
}

paymentGateway.ExpiryMonth = paymentGatewayMonthsList;
paymentGateway.ExpiryYear = paymentGatewayYearsList;

return View(paymentGateway);
```

It's a fair bit of code, and I find myself repeating this code, in similar formats to re-setup the dropdown lists options should the ModelState.IsValid be false and I want to return back to the view for the user to correct there mistakes.

**HttpPost Action - Code**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ConfirmPayment(PayNowViewModel paymentGatewayForm, FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Post processing actions...
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            selectListItem.Value = i.ToString();
            selectListItem.Text = i.ToString("00");

            paymentGatewayMonthsList.Add(selectListItem);
        }

        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        for (int i = year; i <= year + 10; i++)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            selectListItem.Value = i.ToString();
            selectListItem.Text = i.ToString("00");

            paymentGatewayYearsList.Add(selectListItem);
        }

        form.ExpiryMonth = paymentGatewayMonthsList;
        form.ExpiryYear = paymentGatewayYearsList;

        return View("MakePayment", form);
    }
}
```

What's the best way to centralise this dropdown setup code so its only in one place? At present you'll see a large proportion (the for loops), is exactly repeated twice. A base controller with function? Or is it better to re-setup like the above?

Any advice appreciated!
Mike.

Comment: So the code above is an algorithm that you reuse throughout your project, with some minor differences?

Comment: This is just one example. That specific piece of code is used twice, once to load the form, and once to re-load the form from the post method if the ModelState is invalid (e.g. to send the user back to alter the form). I have 20 plus instances where drop-downs are setup like this and then re-setup again if the modelstate fails, but the code and classes are different for each one.

Comment: You can create a some helper class which contains two static methods, GetPaymentMonthList and GetPaymentYearList which returns appropriate List of SelectListItem. And then you can use it without rewriting it two places.

Comment: A static helper class with two methods as DynamicVariable pointed out is one option. Another option is to create one helper method that takes in `object` as a parameter, then use a factory pattern in the method, i.e. `if (obj is PayNowViewModel) { ... }`

Comment: We use a custom IMetadataAware attribute to be added to the viewmodels. Also, each controller that must load dropdown values is attributed with a custom ActionFilterAttribute. This action filter automatically loads the available options from the backend for every viewmodel property attributed with the IMetadataAware attribute (the attribute indicates which values shall be loaded).

Comment: I wonder if this question has a right answer.

Comment: Agreed, many different ways. I went with a shared function in my controller and called the function when needed. It's inside a `#region` so can be found when needed. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a private method to your controller (the following code assumes your `ExpiryMonth` and `ExpiryYear` properties are `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is all that the `DropDownListFor()` method requires)

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(PayNowViewModel model)
{
  model.ExpiryMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(m => new SelectListItem
  {
    Value = m.ToString(),
    Text = m.ToString("00")
  });
  model.ExpiryYear = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year, 10).Select(y => new SelectListItem
  {
    Value = y.ToString(),
    Text = y.ToString("00")
  });
}
```

and then in the GET method

```
public ActionResult ConfirmPayment()
{
  PayNowViewModel model = new PayNowViewModel();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ConfirmPayment(PayNowViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  .... // save and redirect (should not be returning the view here)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the set of your dropdown options is fixed (or recompilation is OK after the potential options change), you can use an enum to store your options.

```
public enum Month {
    // if the dropdown is not required, add default value 0
    Optional = 0, 
    [Display(Name = @"Month_January")]
    January = 1,
    [Display(Name = @"Month_February")]
    February = 2,
    // etc ..
}
```

To render this as a dropdown use an EditorTemplate `Enum.cshtml`:

```
  @model Enum
  @{
      var enumType = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;
      var allValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<object>().ToSelectList(Model);
      // read any attributes like [Required] from ViewData and ModelMetadata ...                
      var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();    
   }

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, allValues, attributes)
```

The `ToSelectList` extension method loops over all enum values and converts them to SelectListItems:

```
    public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) {
        return ToSelectList<T>(list, list.FirstOrDefault());
    }

    public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T selectedItem) {
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var displayAttributeType = typeof(DisplayAttribute);

        foreach (var item in list) {
            string displayName;

            // multi-language: 
            // assume item is an enum value
            var field = item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString());
            try {
                // read [Display(Name = @"someKey")] attribute
                var attrs = (DisplayAttribute)field.GetCustomAttributes(displayAttributeType, false).First();
                // lookup translation for someKey in the Resource file
                displayName =  Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(attrs.Name);
            } catch {
                // no attribute -> display enum value name
                displayName = item.ToString();
            }

            // keep selected value after postback:
            // assume selectedItem is the Model passed from MVC
            var isSelected = false;
            if (selectedItem != null) {
                isSelected = (selectedItem.ToString() == item.ToString());
            }

            items.Add(new SelectListItem {
                Selected = isSelected,
                Text = displayName,
                Value = item.ToString()
            });
        }

        return items;
    }
```

To support multiple languages, add translations for the display name keys, e.g. `"Month_January"`, to the Resource file.

Now that the setup code has been abstracted away using some reflection magic, creating a new viewmodel is a breeze :>

```
public class PayNowViewModel {
    // SelectListItems are only generated if this gets rendered
    public Month ExpiryMonth { get; set; }
}

// Intial Action
var paymentGateway = new PayNowViewModel();
return View(paymentGateway);

// Razor View: call the EditorTemplate 
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExpiryMonth)
```

Note that in the EditorTemplate, `Model` is passed as the selected item to `ToSelectList`. After postback, Model will hold the currently selected value. Therefore it stays selected, even if you just return the model after an error in the controller:

```
// HttpPost Action
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return View("MakePayment", paymentGatewayForm);
}
```

Took us some time to come up with this solution, credits go to the Saratiba team.