# Get list of year in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

How Should I get list of year that generate on basis of current year to next 21 year plus

On controller side I am trying as to get year and passing that model on view side

```
 public IList<SelectListItem> GetYear()
    {            
        var Year= "";                      
        //Hear I want to bind the year in for loop for next years like Current year to next 21 year
        // Some thing like for loop over year
        return Year;
    }

 public ActionResult PaymentInformation(FormCollection fill)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            int StudentRequestId = 0;
            string CurrentURL = "";
            foreach (var key in fill.AllKeys)
            {
                StudentRequestId = Convert.ToInt32(fill["hdstatusstudentrequestid"]);
                CurrentURL = Convert.ToString(fill["hdCurrenturl"]);                    
            }
            ViewBag.StudentRequestId = StudentRequestId;
            ViewBag.CurrentURL = CurrentURL;
            var Year = GetYear();
            var model = new PaymentInformation { AvailableYear = Year };
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

And my model side is I have created list item to get list of year

```
public PaymentInformation()
{
AvailableYear = new List<SelectListItem>();
}
```

On view side I have written code to bind the year getting from AvailableYear

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, Model.AvailableYear, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**How can I bind list of year from controller and show it on my above View side?**

Comment: Use the `Enumerable.Range()` method (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926184/mvc-setting-up-html-dropdownlist-on-modelstate-isvalid-false/34938747#34938747) for similar example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `for` loop which adds 21 items to the SelectListItem list, one for each year from current year

```
public IList<SelectListItem> GetYear()
{
    const int numberOfYears = 21;
    var startYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    var endYear = startYear + numberOfYears;

    var yearList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (var i = startYear; i < endYear ; i++)
    {
        yearList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() });
    }
    return yearList;
}
```

Update the `<` to `<=` if you want the `n` (ex:21) years to  start from next year vs current year as needed.

Also, if you are having a view model, why using the dynamic `ViewBag` to transfer data ? Add the `StudentRequestId` and `CurrentURL` properties to your view model (`PaymentInformation`) and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the code of GetYear method as follows.

```
public IList<SelectListItem> GetYear()
{
    var startYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    var yearList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (var i = DateTime.Today.Year; i < DateTime.Today.Year + 21; i++)
    {
        yearList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = i, Text = i.ToString() });
    }
    return yearList;
}
```