# How to show Validation Error in view page where I am sending Model data for drop-down list from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a country model(Id, Name), Type(id, type of place) model and place(details) model. 
Whenever I want to create a new place I have to send a viewModel that contains country and type lists. 
I have to select the country and type from the drop-down list in View page. I am using DATA ANNOTATION to validate data. The problem is when the input form is invalid I have to show red empty field error and also I have to keep ViewModel data. If I redirect to create page then I can't show the error message and if I use return View('Create') then ViewModel becomes empty. 
How can I do this? 
ViewModel:

```
public class DropDownListViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public PlaceModel Place { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TypeModel> TypeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CountryModel> CountryList { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SelectedType { get; set;  }
    public int SelectedCountry { get; set; }
}

public class PlaceModel:BaseClassModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Address is required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "Range must be between 1-5 in years.")]
    public int RatingId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public byte[] img { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveNewPlace(DropDownListViewModel EditedModel)
    {   
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            DBhandler db = new DBhandler();

            string Name = EditedModel.Place.Name;
            string Address = EditedModel.Place.Address;
            int RatingId = EditedModel.Place.RatingId;
            int TypeId = EditedModel.SelectedType;
            int CountryId = EditedModel.SelectedCountry;
            if (EditedModel.Place.Id >= 1)
            {
                int Id = EditedModel.Place.Id;
                db.Update(Id, Name, Address, RatingId, TypeId, CountryId);
            }
            else
            {
                db.Insert(Name, Address, RatingId, TypeId, CountryId);
            }
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Create");
        }
    }

public ActionResult Create()
    {
        DBhandler manager = new DBhandler();
        DropDownListViewModel list = new DropDownListViewModel();
        list.CountryList = manager.GetCountries();
        list.TypeList = manager.GetTypes();
        return View(list);
    }
```

view:

```html
@model TouristPlace.Models.DropDownListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>View</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveNewPlace","Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>PlaceModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Place.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Place.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Place.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Place.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Place.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Place.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Place.RatingId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Place.RatingId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", min = "1", max = "5", value = "1" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Place.RatingId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SelectedType", new SelectList(Model.TypeList, "Id", "Name"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCountry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCountry", new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Id", "Name"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCountry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Don't redirect, send back your viewmodel to the view  return View("Index", EditedModel);

Comment: It actually doesn't work. gives me this error. <br>The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TouristPlace.Models.DropDownListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TouristPlace.Models.PlaceModel]'.

Comment: That is a very common pattern. Populate your dropdowns in a private method in the controller and call it from the GET and POST if ModelState is invalid. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926184/mvc-setting-up-html-dropdownlist-on-modelstate-isvalid-false). We use 3rd party dropdowns (Kendo) that can make their own AJAX calls to populate dropdowns.

Comment: worked. great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without specifying the return page so:

```
else
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that search view page of same name as SaveNewPlace ?

Comment: Well from my understanding if you specify a return page like this: return View("Index"); it will reload the page and your model containing your errors will be gone. You want to return the same model back to the page or just come back to the view. Remember that your Model contains the errors, you have to keep it

Comment: yes. that is happening. but I keep only view() it will search the view similar name to the controller method.